# How to add javascript into Wordpress sidebar

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I want to put accordeon area into my Wordpress sidebar (not .com)

Therefore you know I must add a little bit JS codes. But WP ignore that. Here the codes are

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.heptasarim.com/wp-content/themes/clean-v1.2/js/hizmetler.js'>
</script>

<div id="panel" style="display:none; background-color: #4ab4d7; padding: 20px; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; text-align: center; border-bottom: 1px solid #337689">
SEO Hizmetleri
</div>

<a href="#" class="buton" style="display: block; width: 176px; height: 27px; text-indent: -9999; margin: 0 auto; margin-top: -1px; position: relative">Buton</a>
```

but somehow I could not with this way. Example (top right on sidebar) [Kurumsal SEO](http://www.heptasarim.com/kurumsal-seo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery library included with WordPress loads in "**no conflict**" mode, i.e. the `$` shortcut is not available and the longer `jQuery` is used :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers

Comment: So must it be in this way ? 
    `jQuery(document).ready(function(){


                $("a.buton").click(function(){
                
                        
                        $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
                
                });
        
        });`